# Getting the following error: Unable to resolve "../assets/icon.png" from "app\assets\screens\WelcomeScreen.js"

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to run my app I get the error
Unable to resolve "../assets/icon.png" from "app\assets\screens\WelcomeScreen.js"
Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
• Field: icon - cannot access file at './assets/icon.png'.

I created a screens folder and input my homescreen into it as I heard that the majority of the react native community does things that way. Attached is a picture of my files[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocNvm.png)

I think that the image path is off, however I had changed it multiple times and am still getting the same error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:  ../icon.png
Cause that's what I can see from your file structure.
If you use visual studio code as dev tool, when you type path cue, correct path will be appeared. so you can avoid to make mistake in path of image.

Comment: Thank You very much it worked it threw the formatting off I'll tinker around with it a bit and find a fix. Again thanks for the help. Update I deleted my code put it back in and the formatting is completely fine thanks again